# how to solve date was not recognized as valid date time?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using parsexcact method to convert data into a specific format, but it throws an exception that date is not invalid.

```
DateTime t = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(t.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note, that you use `CurrentCulture` in `t.ToString()`, but `InvariantCulture` (and, probably, the different format) when `ParseExact` the string back to DateTime

Comment: It is all explained in the documentation for the [`DateTime.ParseExact Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact).

Comment: `t.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Comment: Yes, please don't do that. If imgur.com is blocked (which is quite common) all you see is "enter image description here" and clicking the link does nothing...

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko , its not working still it shows same error

Comment: Do note that a DateTime value *doesn't* have a format. That format only is applied when you do a .ToString()

Comment: @teju1 - What makes you think that a `string` in the form of `2020-02-18 00:00:00` can be parsed with a template of `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: DateTime t = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime t1 = t.AddHours(23);
            DateTime t23 = t1.AddMinutes(3);
            String s = Convert.ToString(t23);


            DateTime date3 = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  , @Enigmativity show same error

Comment: @teju1 see my update

Comment: @teju1 - When I run the code in your comment I get `s` is `"2020/02/19 23:03:00"`. So, again, it doesn't match the pattern `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"`. You would need to parse with `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

(I changed `t.ToString()` to `t.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`)

```
DateTime t = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(t.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```